# -bash: history: /home/.bash_history: cannot create: No such file or directory

Tags: google-cloud-shell

I have run sudo rm -rf $Home command which deleted the home directory of cloud shell. now I am not able to add any folders and not able to use any code. Can someone please help me how I can start adding the folders in cloud shell?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [Resetting Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/resetting-cloud-shell#resetting), you should restart Cloud Shell after deleting your home directory to reset it to default state.

Comment: Thanks MaratB. I have just searched for my WORKSPACE name in the cloud shell. and opened it. I can use the cloud shell now.